# Google Calendar Connector - Mule - Apikit

Tags: api, mule, google-calendar-api

Well im trying to use the GCalendar connector in MuleStudio, the conector recibes an instance of org.mule.module.google.calendar.model.Event ([See Doc](http://mulesoft.github.io/google-calendar-connector/java/org/mule/module/google/calendar/model/Event.html))

How can i create an instance of the Event and pass it to the connector for it to create the event in GCalendar?

Here an image of the case 
[See Image](http://prntscr.com/49o9g2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MEL(Mule Expression Language) using standard Java syntax or expressions to create an instance of the Event class or you can use Spring etc. Here's a rough example that builds a list with an event and sets it as the payload:

```
        <expression-component>
            event = new org.mule.module.google.calendar.model.Event();
            event.location = "America";
            eventTime = org.mule.module.google.calendar.model.EventDateTime();
            eventTime.date = "2015-12-16"'
            event.start = eventTime;
            event.end = eventTime;
            message.payload = [event]
        </expression-component>
```

You can then pass it by reference tot the connector using #[payload]

```
<google-calendars:batch-insert-event calendarId="bla@gmail.com" calendarEvents="#[payload]" />
```

Comment: Ryan, i did this, but the api console is not showing anymore when i run the project. why could this be happening?